# Error from connect to the local instances of SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I got some error messages from connect to the local instances of SQL Server in c# window form.

Please help, Thanks.

> *The name 'lstLocalInstances' does not exist in the current context*

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo; 
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.Win32;


RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey
        (@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
String[] instances = (String[])rk.GetValue("InstalledInstances");
if (instances.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (String element in instances)
    {
        if (element == "MSSQLSERVER")
            lstLocalInstances.Items.Add(System.Environment.MachineName);
        else
            lstLocalInstances.Items.Add(System.Environment.MachineName + @"\" + element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `lstLocalInstances` defined? have you misspelled it? does such a named listbox exist on your form? This is a compile-time error, not  a runtime exception.

Comment: You're trying to access a variable that you haven't defined... and that is invalid (variables can't start with a number)

Comment: +1 to what shahkalpesh said.  Can you please post the method that contains the code sample you provided above?

Comment: i has not define it, and this code simple from "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123441/SQL-Server-2008-Backup-and-Restore-Databases-using"

Answer (score 2):

**In short:** add declaration for your Local instances. Like in the following sample:

```
var lstLocalInstances = new List<string> {"instance1", "instance2"};
// the rest of the code where lstLocalInstances is used

RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey
        (@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
String[] instances = (String[])rk.GetValue("InstalledInstances");
if (instances.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (String element in instances)
    {
        if (element == "MSSQLSERVER")
            lstLocalInstances.Items.Add(System.Environment.MachineName);
        else
            lstLocalInstances.Items.Add(System.Environment.MachineName + @"\" + element);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** From the [code-project link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123441/SQL-Server-2008-Backup-and-Restore-Databases-using) , it seems like  `lstLocalInstances` is actually a **win-form list-box** control in the project example. My advice would be download the source code and run it as is.

In addition, your code need something like :

```
lstLocalInstances.Items.add(new ListBoxItem("name", "value"));
```

Comment: still has some error message; Invalid expression term 'string' 
Syntax error; value expected 
; expected

Comment: this code simple from "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123441/SQL-Server-2008-Backup-and-Restore-Databases-using"

Comment: the lstLocalInstances is actually a list-box control in that example. Thus, you need something like `list.Items.add(new ListBoxItem("name", "value"));`

Comment: @Kam2012, no problem, feel free to mark the answer as helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The programmer from the [codeproject site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123441/SQL-Server-2008-Backup-and-Restore-Databases-using%22) left parts of the code out of the body of the article for brevity.

You need to click the "[Download Source](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLServer_Backup_SMO/SQLServerDatabaseBackupRestore_src.zip)" link at the top of the article to get the full compilable code or fill in the missing pieces yourself.